# Rerun failed Feature Upgrade

Tags: feature-upgrade

Is it possible to rerun a feature upgrade? I have this situation where the feature upgrade fails to create a SitePage. The feature version is updated, is there some way to rerun the upgrade without updating the Feature XML and doing a new deploy?

Answer (score 0):

look this http://spfeatureupgrade.codeplex.com/

Comment: I couldn't find any functionality to run a upgrade again, if the version ha been increased.